# Keras apply different weight to different misclassification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am trying to implement a classification problem with three classes: 'A','B' and 'C', where I would like to incorporate penalty for different type of misclassification in my model loss function (kind of like weighted cross entropy). Class weight is not suited as it applies-to all data that belongs to the class. Eg True label 'B' getting misclassified as 'C' should have higher loss as compared to getting misclassified as 'A'. Weight table as follow:

```
   A  B  C  
A  1  1  1  
B  1  1  1.2 
C  1  1  1
```

In current categorical_crossentropy loss, for true class 'B' if I have prediction softmax as

```
0.5 0.4 0.1  vs 0.1 0.4 0.5
```

categorical_crossentropy will be same. It doesn't matter if 'B' is getting miss-classified as A or C. I want to increase the loss of second prediction softmax as compared to first one.

I have tried https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115  but none of the code is working for Keras v2. Any help where I can directly enforce the weight matrix into Keras loss function will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Building on issue #2115, I've coded the following solution and [posted it there too](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115#issuecomment-530762739).
I only tested it in Tensorflow 1.14, so I guess it should work with Keras v2.

---

Adding to the `class` solution here in [#2115 (comment)](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115#issuecomment-490079116)
here's a more robust and vectorized implementation:

```py
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.losses import CategoricalCrossentropy


class WeightedCategoricalCrossentropy(CategoricalCrossentropy):

    def __init__(self, cost_mat, name='weighted_categorical_crossentropy', **kwargs):
        assert(cost_mat.ndim == 2)
        assert(cost_mat.shape[0] == cost_mat.shape[1])

        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.cost_mat = K.cast_to_floatx(cost_mat)

    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred):

        return super().__call__(
            y_true=y_true,
            y_pred=y_pred,
            sample_weight=get_sample_weights(y_true, y_pred, self.cost_mat),
        )


def get_sample_weights(y_true, y_pred, cost_m):
    num_classes = len(cost_m)

    y_pred.shape.assert_has_rank(2)
    y_pred.shape[1].assert_is_compatible_with(num_classes)
    y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)

    y_pred = K.one_hot(K.argmax(y_pred), num_classes)

    y_true_nk1 = K.expand_dims(y_true, 2)
    y_pred_n1k = K.expand_dims(y_pred, 1)
    cost_m_1kk = K.expand_dims(cost_m, 0)

    sample_weights_nkk = cost_m_1kk * y_true_nk1 * y_pred_n1k
    sample_weights_n = K.sum(sample_weights_nkk, axis=[1, 2])

    return sample_weights_n
```

Usage:

```py
model.compile(loss=WeightedCategoricalCrossentropy(cost_matrix), ...)
```

---

Similarly, this can be applied for the `CategoricalAccuracy` metric too:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import CategoricalAccuracy


class WeightedCategoricalAccuracy(CategoricalAccuracy):

    def __init__(self, cost_mat, name='weighted_categorical_accuracy', **kwargs):
        assert(cost_mat.ndim == 2)
        assert(cost_mat.shape[0] == cost_mat.shape[1])

        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.cost_mat = K.cast_to_floatx(cost_mat)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):

        return super().update_state(
            y_true=y_true,
            y_pred=y_pred,
            sample_weight=get_sample_weights(y_true, y_pred, self.cost_mat),
        )
```

Usage:

```py
model.compile(metrics=[WeightedCategoricalAccuracy(cost_matrix), ...], ...)
```

Comment: How would this look for SparseCategoricalCrossentropy?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the loss function for something that multiplies the loss values by the appropriate weighting in your matrix.

So, by way of an example, consider the [mnist tensorflow example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials):

```py
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

if we wanted to change this in order to weight the losses based on the following matrix:

```py
weights  = tf.constant([
       [1., 1.2, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.2, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 10.9, 1.2, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0.9, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

then we could wrap the existing `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` in a new custom loss function that multiplies the loss by the appropriate weighting. Something like this:

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  # get the prediction from the final softmax layer:
  pred_idx = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)

  # stack these so we have a tensor of [[predicted_i, actual_i], ...,] for each i in batch
  indices = tf.stack([tf.reshape(pred_idx, (-1,)), 
                       tf.reshape(tf.cast( y_true, tf.int32), (-1,))
                     ], axis=1)

  # use tf.gather_nd() to convert indices to the appropriate weight from our matrix [w_i, ...] for each i in batch
  batch_weights = tf.gather_nd(weights, indices)


  return batch_weights * tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

We can then use this new custom loss function in the model:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=custom_loss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```